# android.text Editable がインポートできない

Tags: android-studio

Androidアプリを作りたいと思い、Android Studioをインストールして、本の通りに勉強していた所、上記のtextEditableが importできず先に進めません。
勉強不足で申し訳ありませんがどなたか御教示して頂けませんか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 実際のコードや「import出来ない」と判断した情報（エラーメッセージ等）があると、回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: cubickさんコメントありがとうございます。

Comment: 貼って頂いた画像だと左半分が不要ですし、肝心のメッセージ部分が途切れてしまっていますので、この場合はキャプチャよりメッセージを書き写してもらった方が分かりやすいです。

Answer (score 1):

英語版StackOverFlowに関連しそうな質問がありました。

表示されているワーニング "Unused import statement" は最適化の機能が働いているのが原因のようなので、うまく動作しない場合には`settings > Editor > Auto Import`で機能を無効にしてみてください。

参考：
[Why used import statement is specified as "unused import statement" in Android Studio? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698859/why-used-import-statement-is-specified-as-unused-import-statement-in-android-s)

Comment: 再度の回答ありがとうございます。Auto importで機能を無効にしたところReports any import statements that are unused. Since IDEA can automatically detect and fix such statements with its "Optimize Imports" command, this inspection is mostly useful for off-line reporting on code bases that you don't intend to change.
 Unused import statementと出ました

Comment: 他にUnused import と出ており未だimportできていないみたいです。英語版のStackoverflowを見たところ類似の質問もないようなので、android studioをご使用されているなら宜しければtext.editableの代わりになるパッケージを教えていただけませんか？

Comment: +票しました、現状Android Studioもバージョンがあがりこうした問題は最早出づらいような気もしますが、私も何度か遭遇したことがあります。Android Studioのキャッシュの削除や、プロジェクトのClean/Rebuild、などをしていると症状が改善したことがあります。